# Combining 2 normal probability plots in same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 `normal probability plots` as below

```
library(ggplot2)

# Plot 1
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), col='red') + 
  stat_function(fill='red', fun = dnorm, xlim = c(-4, -1), geom = "area") + 
  stat_function(fill='red', fun = dnorm, xlim = c(-1, 4), geom = "area", alpha = 0.3) 

# Plot 2
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 2), col='blue') + 
  stat_function(fill='blue', fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 2), xlim = c(-4, -1), geom = "area") + 
  stat_function(fill='blue', fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 2), xlim = c(-1, 4), geom = "area", alpha = 0.3)
```

Individually they are just fine. However I wanted to combine these 2 plots and place them in same plot window with same `x-axis`.

I also want to add a `legend` based on `fill` color in the combined plot to distinguish them.

Is there any way to achieve this with `ggplot`?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine both the `stat_function`s and create two with an `aes` for your `fill` to create a legend with `scale_fill_manual` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), col='red') + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, xlim = c(-4, -1), geom = "area", aes(fill = "plot 1")) + 
  stat_function(fill='red', fun = dnorm, xlim = c(-1, 4), geom = "area", alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 2), col='blue') + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 2), xlim = c(-4, -1), geom = "area", aes(fill = "plot 2")) + 
  stat_function(fill='blue', fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 2), xlim = c(-1, 4), geom = "area", alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>